# Gcc searches for header files under the wrong directory

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I have two versions of gcc/g++ installed: gcc-4.5(installed from package manager, binary files are under /usr/bin, header files are under /usr/include) and gcc-4.4.3(compiled by myself, put under /opt/gcc-4.4.3).

When I made gcc/g++ 4.4.3 to be the default version (using "update-alternatives" to make /usr/bin/gcc and /usr/bin/g++ point to the corresponding one under directory "/opt/gcc-4.4.3/bin") and compiled the files, it always reported the following errors:

> /usr/include/c++/4.5/bits/basic_string.h:1659: undefined reference to
>   `std::basic_string,
>   std::allocator::_S_construct_aux_2(unsigned long, char,
>   std::allocator const&)'

It seems that the compiler is trying to find the header files for c++ under /usr/include/c++/4.5, which causes the link error. When I changed the default version of gcc to gcc-4.5, the errors disappeared.

So how could I make the compiler search for the header files under the correct directory "/opt/gcc-4.4.3/include"? I have tried to export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH, but it seems not work.

PS: gcc -v

```
Using build-in specs
Target: x86_64-suse-linux
Configured with: ./configure --prefix=/opt/gcc-4.4.3
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.4.3 (GCC)
```

Comment: Did you try to add `-I/full/path/to/the/header` when trying to compile with `4.4.3`?

Comment: @meh I'm trying to change the default search path of g++ from /usr/include to /opt/gcc-4.4.5/include, so -I/full/path/to/the/header can't solve my problem.

Comment: Yeah, I thought so, but I wasn't sure. Can't help, sorry.

Comment: What does `g++ -v` say is the include path?

Comment: @MatsPetersson I added it in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try compiling gcc 4.4.3 again, but use the [`--with-gxx-include-dir=/opt/gcc-4.4.3/include`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/configure.html) option in the configure step.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to get to that with my `g++ -v`.

Comment: No worries - I was just trying to say "Yes, I think that's the right answer".

Comment: How on earth should I know about having to set --with-gxx-include-dir besides having already set --prefix? And if that works at all, what about library search directories then?? As a dumb application developer I'm already spending weeks of desperately trying to use a self built GCC. I'm too exhausted even in order to formulate a sound question myself, similar or same topic. Sorry for being emotional here. At least I'm going to try the suggested option. Thanks so far. But what about library paths (link time and run time)?

Answer (score 1):

It might be an issue with what `update-alternatives` has done, or not done.

When I build an alternate compiler I tend to use a `--prefix` *and* `--program-suffix=-XY` just so I can spot problems. Check which `cpp` is being run:

```
/opt/gcc-4.4.3/bin/g++ --print-prog-name=cpp
cpp -v </dev/null
/opt/gcc-4.4.3/bin/cpp -v < /dev/null
/opt/gcc-4.4.3/bin/g++ -print-search-dirs | grep '^programs:'
```

(you can also  check `ld` and `as` with `--print-prog-name`)

Setting `CPPFLAGS="-v -H`" during a build may help track things down too.

An ugly workaround might be `CPPFLAGS="-nostdinc -nostdinc++ -I/opt/gcc-4.4.3/include/"` but it's better to fix your compile environment, as that's likely to cause as many problems as it solves. There are also options `-isystem` and `-sysroot` to help in certain cases, see http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Invocation.html .